# TestNG expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp and externalized messages

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, localization, testng

I'm using TestNG for my unit tests and I'd like to check exception messages. OK, `@Test(expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = ...)` is exactly what I need, right? Well, at the same time I'd like to externalize my messages so they aren't mixed with my code. I'm loosely following [a guide by Brian Goetz](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075897/testing-debugging/exceptional-practices--part-3.html), so my exception code looks like

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format(
    EXCEPTIONS.getString(EX_NOT_A_VALID_LETTER), c));
```

Works perfectly for me, except these two things don't exactly mix. I can't write

```
@Test(dataProvider = "getInvalidLetters",
    expectedExceptions = {IllegalArgumentException.class},
    expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = regexize(EXCEPTIONS.getString(EX_NOT_A_VALID_LETTER)))
```

Here, `regexize` is a function that is supposed to replace `{0}`-style placeholders with `.*`. However, this fails with a “element value must be a constant expression”. Makes sense, since it's needed at compile time. But what are possible workarounds?

I can imagine a test code generator that would replace these constructs with real message regexps, but it would be a pain to integrate it with IDE, SCM, build tools and so on.

Another option is to use `try-catch` and check exception message manually. But this is ugly.

Lastly, I think it should be possible to hack TestNG with something like

```
@Test(expectedExceptionsMessageBundle = "bundle.name.goes.here",
      expectedExceptionsMessageLocaleProvider = "functionReturningListOfLocales"
      expectedExceptionsMessageKey = "MESSAGE_KEY_GOES_HERE")
```

This would be a great thing, really. Except that it won't be the same TestNG that Maven fetches for me from the repo. Another option is to implement this, contribute a patch to TestNG and wait for it to be released. I'm seriously considering this option now, but maybe there's an easier way? Haven't I missed something obvious? I can't possibly be the only one with this issue!

Or maybe I'm externalizing my messages in a wrong way. But a guy like Brian Goetz can't be wrong, now can he? Or did *I* get him wrong?

**Update**

Based on the answer given here, I've made [a tutorial on the topic](http://www.tachenov.name/2016/testng-and-netbeans-testing-exceptions-with-externalized-messages/), covering some pitfalls, especially when using NetBeans 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using an [annotation transformer](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers) here?

You will be able to do something like:

```
@LocalizedException(expectedExceptionsMessageBundle = "bundle.name.goes.here",
      expectedExceptionsMessageLocaleProvider = "functionReturningListOfLocales"
      expectedExceptionsMessageKey = "MESSAGE_KEY_GOES_HERE")
@Test(dataProvider = "getInvalidLetters",
      expectedExceptions = {IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void test() {
  // ...
}
```

Where the annotation transformer will look like:

```
public class LocalizedExceptionTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
  public void transform(ITest annotation, Class testClass,
      Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    if (testMethod != null) {
      LocalizedException le = testMethod.getAnnotation(LocalizedException.class);
      if (le != null) {
         String regexp = regexize(le);
         annotation.setExpectedExceptionsMessageRegExp(regexp);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks very much exactly what I need, except that I can't seem to find any tutorial on how to turn annotation transformers into real annotations, like in your example. The docs say register the transformer as a listener, which is also acceptable, but your example looks much better than fiddling with command line and listeners.

Comment: Oh, got it. You mean to make transformer to actually *detect* and use an existing annotation. But is it possible for a class to be an annotation? I thought annotations were interfaces...

Comment: `@LocalizedException` is a custom annotation and `ITest` is a TestNG object which contains information copied from `@Test` at init time. Does it answer your question?

Comment: If `@LocalizedException` is a custom annotation, then why declare `public class LocalizedException`? That's what confused me. Right now I'm trying to implement `@ExpectedExceptionsMessageKey` (annotation) and `ExceptionRegExpTransformer` (transformer class), that's how I understand it.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. Renamed to `LocalizedExceptionTransformer`